# conda init on WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is EXTREMELY slow

Tags: conda, miniconda

I installed `miniconda3` on `WSL2` running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. During the install - chose to not run `conda` init automatically every time I created a terminal.

Essentially -- I run the following in order to initialize `conda`:
/c/work/miniconda/bin/conda

which then invokes the following python code (I am running Python 3.10.12):

```
#!/c/work/miniconda/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
# Before any more imports, leave cwd out of sys.path for internal 'conda shell.*' commands.
# see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6549
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':
    # The standard first entry in sys.path is an empty string,
    # and os.path.abspath('') expands to os.getcwd().
    del sys.path[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from conda.cli import main
    sys.exit(main())
```

Running the following gives me a time of ~2minutes.

```
$ date; . ~/.conda-init.bash ; date
Fri Dec 22 20:11:48 EST 2023
Fri Dec 22 20:13:32 EST 2023
```

I don't believe this could be "normal".  Any suggestions on how this can be speeded up?

Comment: Btw, you should update Python 3.12.1, This will give you a free bug.